# Adding a Decimal Point button to the calculator app

Tags: swift, calculator

Can someone please add the code to this so I'm able to add a decimal point button?

This is what I have so far, can someone please fill in the code required for the decimal point button. so I can learn from it. please view over the code and let me know what you think.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var numberOnScreen:Double = 0;
    var previousNumber:Double = 0;
    var preformingMath = false
    var operation = 0;

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func numbers(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if preformingMath == true
        {
            label.text = String(sender.tag-1)
            numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
            preformingMath = false
        }
        else
        {
            label.text = label.text! + String(sender.tag-1)
            numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
        }
    }


    @IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 11 && sender.tag != 16
        {
            previousNumber = Double(label.text!)!

            if sender.tag == 12 //Divide
            {
                label.text = "/";
            }
            else if sender.tag == 13//Multiply
            {
                label.text = "x";
            }
            else if sender.tag == 14 //Minus
            {
                label.text = "-";
            }
            else if sender.tag == 15 //Plus
            {
                label.text = "+";
            }
            operation = sender.tag;
            preformingMath = true;
        }
        else if sender.tag == 16
        {
            if operation == 12
            {
                label.text = String(previousNumber / numberOnScreen)
            }
            else if operation == 13
            {
                label.text = String(previousNumber * numberOnScreen)
            }
            else if operation == 14
            {
                label.text = String(previousNumber - numberOnScreen)
            }
            else if operation == 15
            {
              label.text = String(previousNumber + numberOnScreen)
            }
        }
        else if sender.tag == 11
        {
            label.text = ""
            previousNumber = 0;
            numberOnScreen = 0;
            operation = 0;
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Comment: Give it a try.  If `performingMath` is `true`, set `label.text` to `"0."`, otherwise append `"."` to `label.text` if it doesn't have a decimal.  Then update `numberOnScreen` with `Double(label.text!)!`.

Comment: Use `if label.text.contains(".") { }` to test if there is already a decimal.

Comment: There is no need for the trailing semicolons `;` in Swift.  When testing a `Bool`, there is no need to compare to `true`.  Just use the `Bool`: for example `if performingMath { }`.

Comment: Could you send me a screenshot of your code in mine? I've still no luck. thanks

Comment: See my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this `@IBAction` to your code and hook it to your `.` button.

- If the user presses `.` before any numbers, the display will be set to `0.`.
- If there are numbers in the display, then `.` will be appended to the display if there isn't already a decimal point in the number.
- Finally, the `numberOnScreen` will be updated.

  ```
  @IBAction func decimal(_ sender: UIButton) {
      if preformingMath || label.text!.isEmpty
      {
          label.text = "0."
          preformingMath = false
      }
      else
      {
          if !label.text!.contains(".") {
              label.text = label.text! + "."
          }
      }
      numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
  }
  ```

Comment: Problem, with this code it all work apart from when for instance, I want to write 2.3... as soon as I press the decimal button it resets to 0.  ... but if I press 0.2 for instance starting the sum with a 0 it works? Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me. You must have something different in your code. Can you add a new section to your question that includes all of your code and I’ll take a look.

Comment: There I updated my current code above, get back to me as soon as you can

Comment: So, if you hit CLEAR, and then `2` `.` your display reads `0.`?

Comment: Your code is working for me.  You need to give me a better description of how exactly to reproduce your problem.  What are the minimal keystrokes starting with CLEAR to show the problem?

Comment: in the simulator when I hit 0 then . then 1 it shows on the label as 0.1 ... as it should! When I hit the . the label shows 0. as it should but when I hit from number 1 to 7 then the . the label goes back to 0.

Comment: So if you start off with a `7`, the display shows `7`.  And when you hit `.`, the display then goes to `0.`?

Comment: I think you have a button wiring problem. Bring up the code and Viewcontroller side by side in Xcode.  Hover over the circle next to the `numbers` function and make sure only the numbers are wired to it.  Hover over the circle next to `buttons` and make sure only `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `=`, and `C` are wired to it.  Hover over circle next to `decimal` function and make sure only `.` is wired to it.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like your `.` button is connected to both the `decimal` function and the `buttons` function.  If so, in the Interface Builder, control-click on the decimal button and click on the `x` next to `ViewController` `buttons:` in the **Sent Events** section.

Comment: Yep that was it, both connected to the number and buttons function! Thank you buddy, great job !!